# sympy type ,class:I want to use type,isinstance to determine the class

Tags: sympy

①sympy type ,class:I want to use type,isinstance to determine the class.

②c langage:printf function?　python:print statement output −−−−〉variable ok (2022-02-20)

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/special_topics/classification.html

```
from sympy import *
var('n x y ')
def myType(f):
   if  isinstance(f,Add)  :
       print("#",f,"This is Add")
   if  isinstance(f,And)  :
       print("#",f,"This is And")
   # if type(f) = <class 'sympy.core.relational.StrictLessThan'>:
   #    print("This is StrictLessThan")
   # if type(f) = <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>:
   #    print("This is Symbol")
   # if type(f) = <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Infinity'>:
   #    print("This is Infinity")
   return
f0=x+y
f1=(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)
f2=n < oo
# f3=oo
# f4=n > 6.1875
# f5=n
# f6=6.18750000000000
myType(f0)
myType(f1)
myType(f2)
# myType(f3)
# myType(f4)
# myType(f5)
# myType(f6)

# x + y This is Add
# (n > 6.1875) & (n < oo) This is And
# .....error
```

Comment: It's not clear what question you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The string representation of an object is not what you need to test against.

```
>>> isinstance(n < oo, Lt)
True
>>> isinstance(n, Symbol)
True
>>> oo is oo  # special "singleton can be tested with `is`
True
>>> isinstance(oo, Number)
True
```